# Why does this lock free queue work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, lock-free

I'm rewriting an old lock free queue implementation, I started by using memory_order_relaxed for everything with the intention of tightening up the memory semantics and adding standalone fences etc later. But strangely, it's working.. I've tried compiling with both XCode and VS2015 with maxxed out optimisation settings. I had code very similar to this failing about 1-1.5 years ago, the last time I wrote this.

Here's my queue:

```
#ifndef __LOCKFREEMPMCQUEUE_H__
#define __LOCKFREEMPMCQUEUE_H__

#include <atomic>

template <typename T> 
class LockFreeMPMCQueue
{
    public:

    explicit LockFreeMPMCQueue(size_t size)
        : m_data(new T[size])
        , m_size(size)
        , m_head_1(0)
        , m_head_2(0)
        , m_tail_1(0)
        , m_tail_2(0)
    {
    }

    virtual ~LockFreeMPMCQueue() { delete m_data; }

    bool try_enqueue(const T& value)
    {
        size_t tail = m_tail_1.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        const size_t head = m_head_2.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        const size_t count = tail - head;

        if (count == m_size)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&m_tail_1, &tail, (tail + 1), std::memory_order_relaxed,
                                   std::memory_order_relaxed) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }

        m_data[tail % m_size] = value;

        while (m_tail_2.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != tail)
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
        m_tail_2.store(tail + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

        return true;
    }

    bool try_dequeue(T& out)
    {
        size_t head = m_head_1.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        const size_t tail = m_tail_2.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

        if (head == tail)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&m_head_1, &head, (head + 1), std::memory_order_relaxed,
                                   std::memory_order_relaxed) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }

        out = m_data[head % m_size];

        while (m_head_2.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != head)
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
        m_head_2.store(head + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

        return true;
    }

    size_t capacity() const { return m_size; }

    private:
    T* m_data;
    size_t m_size;
    std::atomic<size_t> m_head_1;
    std::atomic<size_t> m_head_2;
    std::atomic<size_t> m_tail_1;
    std::atomic<size_t> m_tail_2;
};

#endif
```

And here's the test I wrote:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include "LockFreeMPMCQueue.h"

std::chrono::microseconds::rep test(LockFreeMPMCQueue<size_t>& queue, char* memory, const size_t num_threads, const size_t num_values)
{
    memset(memory, 0, sizeof(char) * num_values);

    const size_t num_values_per_thread = num_values / num_threads;

    std::thread* reader_threads = new std::thread[num_threads];
    std::thread* writer_threads = new std::thread[num_threads];

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        reader_threads[i] = std::thread([i, &queue, memory, num_values_per_thread]()
                        {
                            for (size_t x = 0; x < num_values_per_thread; ++x)
                            {
                                size_t value;
                                while (!queue.try_dequeue(value))
                                {
                                }
                                memory[value] = 1;
                            }
                        });
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        writer_threads[i] = std::thread([i, &queue, num_values_per_thread]()
                        {
                            const size_t offset = i * num_values_per_thread;
                            for (size_t x = 0; x < num_values_per_thread; ++x)
                            {
                                const size_t value = offset + x;
                                while (!queue.try_enqueue(value))
                                {
                                }
                            }
                        });
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        reader_threads[i].join();
        writer_threads[i].join();
    }

    auto time_taken = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;

    delete[] reader_threads;
    delete[] writer_threads;

    bool fail = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_values; ++i)
    {
        if (memory[i] == 0)
        {
            printf("%u = 0\n", i);
            fail = true;
        }
    }

    if (fail)
    {
        printf("FAIL!\n");
    }

    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time_taken).count();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const size_t num_threads_max = 16;
    const size_t num_values = 1 << 12;
    const size_t queue_size = 128;
    const size_t num_samples = 128;

    LockFreeMPMCQueue<size_t> queue( queue_size );
    char* memory = new char[num_values];

    const double inv_num_samples = 1.0 / double( num_samples );

    for( size_t num_threads = 1; num_threads <= num_threads_max; num_threads *= 2 )
    {
        double avg_time_taken = 0.0;

        for( size_t i = 0; i < num_samples; ++i )
        {
            avg_time_taken += test( queue, memory, num_threads, num_values ) * inv_num_samples;
        }

        printf("%u threads, %u ms\n", num_threads, avg_time_taken);
    }

    delete[] memory;

    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Code with bugs often does something other than what you expect. That's why we works so hard to avoid bugs.

Comment: Sorry, I did not check your code, but: 1. there is always the problem with concurrent code: it may seem to work... until it fails. Recommendation: write more tests (especially with large amount of treads and running for a long time). 2. x86 architecture has a strong memory model, hiding some mistakes. (for example, wrong code can work on x86 but fail on ARM) 3. Use Thread Sanitizer.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`__LOCKFREEMPMCQUEUE_H__`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: C++ does not have the attractive property that wrong code actually is observed to have consistent bad behaviour, particularly for multithreaded code. My advice is: if you want to know whether a given piece of code has correct behaviour in all conditions made possible in a given memory model, you will never find out by running against real hardware. Instead, implement a virtual machine that implements your desired memory model, compile your code to that virtual machine, and then have the machine simulate all legal orderings of memory access in the model.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that many memory models do not impose the requirement that a *consistent* view of memory access orderings be observed across all threads. So don't fall into the trap in your virtual machine of merely producing all possible orderings of memory as seen by an omniscient global observer; that's not enough. You may have to have all possible orderings of memory accesses *in every thread independently*.

Comment: The code is not lock-free.  You *wait for another thread* to update m_tail_2 and/or m_head_2.

Comment: It is also broken.  Because everything is relaxed, the assignment of the value into the array can happen *after* tail is updated.  You could read data that is not yet written, or half-written.   As others have mentioned, it only appears to work because of the x86 memory model.  But even on x86 I think you could have it fail, it you run it long enough.

Comment: hi @tony, yes indeed it is broken, as I wrote in the question I had not started tightening things down yet, and was surprised it already worked. I think ultimately I was just lucky that the compiler didn't move anything around too much. You're right about it not being lock free, at the time of writing this I did not know the distinction between lock free, wait free, or just "not using a mutex". x86 is very forgiving, a great tool is Relacy, which allows simulating looser memory models. If you're interested, I wrote it all up here http://www.codersblock.org/blog/2016/6/02/ditching-the-mutex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory order only specifies the *minimum guarantee* that you request from the generated code. The compiler and hardware are free to give stronger guarantees as they please.

In particular, note that on x86 platforms many memory accesses are always synchronized by the hardware (for instance, loads on x86 are always sequentially consistent). That is why code that runs perfectly fine on x86 often breaks when ported to ARM or PowerPC without according for the weaker default synchronization on those platforms.

Herb Sutter has a nice comparison table in his [Atomic Weapons talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2) from *C++ and Beyond 2012* (starts at about 31 minutes into the video; or look for the [slides](http://sdrv.ms/NxDB6u) titled *Code Generation*, starting from page 34), where he shows how the different memory orderings may or may not lead to different code generated for different platforms.

Bottom line: Just because your code seems to work fine on your machine now, does not mean that it's correct. That is one major reason why you should not mess around with the memory orderings unless you know *exactly* what you are doing (and even then you probably still shouldn't do it).

Comment: It's strange that it used to fail though.. I've also tried this same code and run it on my iPhone and it was fine. I'm quite happy to go ahead with putting in fences and so on, but I'd just really like a good way to test that the code is actually correct.

Comment: @Joe This is the big problem: There are many tools that can catch certain kinds of (obvious?) errors. But it is very, very hard to proof that the code is actually correct and the tool didn't just miss a subtle race. Your best bet here is probably a formal analysis tool like [TLA](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/tla/tla.html), but those are not exactly straightforward to use. In the end, it simply remains an incredible difficult area to work in.

Comment: btw a great tool for this is Relacy, it allows simulating looser memory models on x86, I wrote up my adventure here http://www.codersblock.org/blog/2016/6/02/ditching-the-mutex